# brew formula not found error for a removed package

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I get this message every time I open a terminal in mac

```
Error: No available formula for php55 
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap josegonzalez/php
```

php is not installed on my system and when I try cleanup of uninstall it get the error

```
Anadis-MacBook-Pro:vagrant-vms anadi$ brew rm php55
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/php55
Anadis-MacBook-Pro:vagrant-vms anadi$ brew cleanup php55
Error: No available formula for php55 
Anadis-MacBook-Pro:vagrant-vms anadi$ brew cleanup php
Error: No available formula for php
```

not sure where it's coming from; how to get rid of this error?